# how to set theme after creat a chartXY object?

Tags: lightningchart

i created chartXY like this:

```
this.chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({container: `${this.chartId}`,theme:Themes.dark})
```

Does anyone know how to change the theme to Themes.light without using lightningChart().ChartXY() again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme for a chart can't be changed after the chart has been created.

The only option is to recreate the chart with the different theme.

```js
const lc = lightningChart()

let chart = lc.ChartXY({theme:Themes.dark})

...

// delete the old chart, also ensure that no references to the old chart is left in application code
chart.dispose()
chart = undefined

// recreate the chart
chart = lc.ChartXY({theme:Themes.light})
```

Comment: thank u！ Besides recreating, can I modify the color through style API(backgroundstyle、linestyle.....) to achieve the purpose of switching themes？

Comment: Yes, all styles that the theme changes can be changed with different combination of different setXStyle, e.g. setFillStyle, setStrokeStyle, setBackgroundFillStyle. All of the styles for theme can be accessed through the theme object, e.g. Themes.light.chartBackgroundFillStyle would be the style to pass to chart.setBackgroundFillStyle() call.